# Conditionally highlighting totals that don't match a dynamically summed range

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, excel-indirect

**Objective:**

I am looking to use conditional formatting to highlight cells in rows that are not equal to the sum of a dynamic range.

**Problem:**

While the formula I have created seems to work when pasted into cells, it does not give the same results when entered as a conditional formula.

**Example:**

Here is a space delimited example to be pasted into "A1":

```
Allo    d1  d2  d3  d4  d5
Total   10  10  10  10  10
A   9   9   10  10  9
B   0   0   0   0   0
C   0   1   0   0   0
Total   12  12  12  12  12
B   0   5   0   3   4
C   12  7   8   8   8
Total   12  12  12  12  12
A   0   0   0   0   0
B   0   0   0   0   0
C   0   5   0   3   4
D   12  7   8   8   8
```

I wrote this formula which shows TRUEs and FALSEs correctly when pasted into "H2" and dragged to the right and down to "L13." When I apply this formula to the data range "B2:F13" it does not mimic what I'd expect.

```
=IF($A2="TOTAL", B2 <> SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(B3),COLUMN(B3),4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(B2)+IFERROR(MATCH("TOTAL",$A3:$A$13,0)-1,ROW($A$13)-ROW($A2)),COLUMN(B2),4))))
```

Below you can see the formula broken out in a more easy to read way. Is my formula flawed/ How can I accomplish what I am trying to do? I appreciate your thoughts.

```
=IF($A2="TOTAL", 
    B2 <> SUM( 
              INDIRECT( ADDRESS( ROW(B3), 
                                 COLUMN(B3), 
                                 4) &":"& 
                        ADDRESS( ROW(B2) + IFERROR( 
                                                   MATCH( "TOTAL", $A3:$A$13, 0)-1, 
                                                   ROW($A$13)-ROW($A2)),
                                 COLUMN(B2),4))))
```

[image]

Comment: What is the condition applied to?

Comment: B2:F13 in this example

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, attaching a picture now.

Comment: Well that's concerning, just edited the picture to show the formula. I have not considered using subtotal for this scenario.

Comment: I am not using subtotal as that would mean I am creating totals from data, while here I have intended totals and am looking to see where the data falls short/long.

Comment: That's exactly what I figured. I found numerous posts questions how to do a indirect within CF and they seemed to work half the time. I suppose it will not work for me. Is there an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use OFFSET instead:

```
=IF($A2="TOTAL",B2<> SUM(OFFSET(B3,0,0,IFERROR(MATCH("TOTAL",$A3:$A$13,0)-1,ROWS($A3:$A$13)),1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Genius use of the height argument. Did not realize one could use offset this way. Thank you!

Comment: I'd like to say that it was my first try, but it took a while to get it correct.

Comment: Happy to present a challenge ;)